# Including different sections of text based on different configuration

Tags: sectioning, document-configuration, options

I'm writing a document in which will eventually be broken into different versions of different length.  Most of the differences will just be which material is included in different versions.  Is there a way to construct a setting that could be changed in the preamble which would determine which sections of text are included in the build?  For example, something like:

```
This sentence is always included.
\level[2]{This sentence is included in the medium and long versions
\level[3]{, while this section is only in the long version}.}
```

which would produce:

`\setlevel{1}`:

> This sentence is always included.

`\setlevel{2}`:

> This sentence is always included.
>   This sentence is included in the medium and long versions.

`\setlevel{3}`:

> This sentence is always included.
>   This sentence is included in the medium and long versions,
>   while this section is only in the long version.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to include some punctuation or spacing adjustments, then the following would suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setlevel}[1]{\gdef\@level{#1}}
\newcommand{\level}[2][\relax]{%
  \unskip
  \ifx\relax#1\else
    \ifnum\@level<#1\else
      #2%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlevel{1}

This sentence is always included.
\level[2]{\@ This sentence is included in the medium and long versions%
\level[3]{, while this section is only in the long version}.}    

\setlevel{2}

This sentence is always included.
\level[2]{\@ This sentence is included in the medium and long versions%
\level[3]{, while this section is only in the long version}.}    

\setlevel{3}

This sentence is always included.
\level[2]{\@ This sentence is included in the medium and long versions%
\level[3]{, while this section is only in the long version}.}    

\end{document}
```

Of course, nesting `\level[<a>]` inside `\level[<b>]` where `<a>`<`<b>` won't help.